# Not working explode() function

Tags: php

I'm crawl some information from other site to using php, So I use DomDocument, DomXpath, and some kinds of php function like explode();

I crawled some table, there is many td datas. anyway I pick up them to text, and divide based on  "[empty space]". but some datas divide well, **but some couldn't.**

Still I don't know why explode() function doesn't work. How can I solve this?

```
<?php


function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}

$src = file_get_contents_curl("http://finance.naver.com/item/main.nhn?code=005930");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($src, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'euckr'));
$stacks =  $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(4)->textContent;
$arr = explode(" ",$stacks);
print_r($arr);


?>
```

Comment: @Uchiha You can see on include line, Thanks.

Comment: From a quick peek it seems to be working fine. Yes, `" "` does not mean newline/tab. Maybe `preg_split('/\s+/', $stacks)` solves this

Comment: @kingkero Thank you very much. I solved this. How can I accept your comment as a accepted answer? and Do you know the reason that coundn't divide by explode()?

Comment: @kingkero You should post you comment comment as response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine. The thing is, there are multiple whitespace and -like characters (tab, newline, ..). Since `explode` looks for literal occurrence, you'd need to check for every single one.

To do this much easier, just use `preg_split()` like so

```
preg_split('/\s+/', $str)
```